# How to validate user from his mobile no by sending validation message?

Tags: java, spring, jsf

How to validate user from his mobile no by sending validation message (or Use any third party API)? In Java JSF, Spring web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It entirely depends on the third party api. Most of them can be called by HTTPRequest in java. They are mere urls and most of time data is passed as url parameters.

Many of them also provide some free sms on registration. You can register and try them out.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I saw some of these sites like way2sms, smsze etc, is this secure?

Comment: Yes, they are secure. In fact, I have been using way2sms for many years.